# Dictionary key count

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python 2.7: I'm measuring a process that counts the keys of a dictionary returned from a function.

A basic example is shown where the function *getList()* returns a list of chars which may be ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] or ['d']; most lists are single elements though two may be returned sometimes, e.g. ['a', 'd']. I'd like to count everything returned. A way I thought of doing this is shown below:

```
    myDict = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0, 'error':0, 'total':0}
    for key in charList:
        myDict[key] += 1
        myDict['total'] += 1
```

**Is there a more Pythonic way, perhaps dictionary comprehension to count keys within lists (of varying length)?**

```
import random

def getList():
    '''mimics a prcoess that returns a list of chars between a - d
       [most lists are single elements, though some are two elements]'''
    number = (random.randint(97,101))
    if number == 101:
        charList = [chr(number-1), chr(random.randint(97,100))]
        if charList[0] == charList[1]:
            getList()            
    else:
        charList = [chr(number)]
    return charList


myDict = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd':0, 'error':0, 'total':0}

for counter in range(0,5):
    charList = getList()
    for key in charList:
        print charList, '\t', key
        try:
            myDict[key] += 1
            myDict['total'] += 1
        except:
            myDict['error'] += 1

print "\n",myDict
```

Output generated:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `collections.Counter` class: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

For example with your code:

```
import collections
ctr = collections.Counter()

for ii in range(0,5):
    charList = getList()
    ctr.update(charList)

ctr['total'] = sum(ctr.values())
print ctr
```

This will print:

```
Counter({'total': 7, 'd': 5, 'a': 1, 'c': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
# You need to initialize the counter or you won't get the entry with 0 count.
myDict = collections.Counter({'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0})
myDict.update(x for _ in range(0, 5) for x in getList())
# Then create the 'total' entry
myDict['total'] = sum(myDict.values())
```

*Note: This may add new keys to the counter without setting the `'error'` entry if the `list` returned by `getList()` contains new characters (`'e'`, `'f'`, ...).*

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter` and a double-loop generator expression for feeding the individual elements into the counter:

```
>>> lst = [['a'], ['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['c', 'd']]
>>> c = collections.Counter((y for x in lst for y in x))
>>> c
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
>>> c.most_common(2)
[('a', 2), ('c', 2)]
>>> sum(c.values())
6
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to flatten your list with `chain` and then use a `Counter`: let `lst` be the list `[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['a', 'd']]`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(chain(*lst))
>>> c['total'] = sum(c.values())
>>> c
Counter({'total': 6, 'd': 2, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})
```